# How to blur or add color with opacity when an Image is clicked [Glide Library]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-glide

I'm using Glide to show images and worked fine. Now when users clicks any image, I need to highlite the image either by showing a tick mark or add a translucent color over it.

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                if (null != images && !images.isEmpty()) {




                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter/wiki/Gallery-tutorial

Comment: How should I use it to apply to my above code?

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml in your adapter:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/image_view" >
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/check_image" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:visibility="Invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

in  **onItemClick()** get ImageView which ID is "**check_image**" and make it **visible**.

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations

```
Glide.with(context)
      .load(R.drawable.check)
      .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25)))
      .into(holder.image)
```